# PHP and JavaScript Dates don't match - Strange anomaly

Tags: php, javascript

HTML/PHP:

```
<button onclick="change_value(<?php echo $date?>)">Go</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function change_value(date_used)
{
    alert(date_used);
}
```

When I right-click on the button and click the "Inspect Element" button shows the parameter correctly, i.e something like this:

```
<button onclick="change_value(2012-08-22)">Go</button>
```

But the `alert` in the JavaScript is displaying `1981`. That's it - only `1981`. Not only the date is wrong, but the format, too.

What is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Because you passed an expression (`2012 - 08 - 22`) instead of a string (`"2012-08-22"`) into `change_value`. It's like asking "Why does `print(3-2);` output `1`?". Use `change_value(<?php echo json_encode($date); ?>)` instead.

Comment: yes , exactly , and you may use a ' instead of json_encode , change_value('<?php echo $date; ?>')

Comment: that's because `2012-08-22 = 2012 - 1 - 22 = 1981`. Your dat is interpreted as a numeric operation and `08` is interpreted as an octal number (08 = 1 in octal)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
<button onclick="change_value(<?php echo $date?>)">Go</button>
```

to this:

```
<button onclick="change_value('<?php echo $date?>')">Go</button>
```

You should pass it as string to JavaScript ...